# Seven Pounds Eight and Eight Pence

Tags: word-choice

In Cedric Mount's one-act play 'The Never Never Nest', Aunt Jane asks Jack:

> How can you pay **seven pounds eight and eight pence** out of six pounds?

I thought **seven pounds eight and eight pence** meant £ 7.88 pence, because after a decimal point, normally the numbers are spoken separately.
But I am told that my understanding is wrong. It is **7 pounds, 8 shillings and 8 pence**.

Which is correct? I hope someone may shed some light on this focusing on shilling and pence details. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That should be "eightpence", spelt as one word. The "pence" is unstressed, with a schwa vowel. (And it's definitely old money.)

Comment: It hasn't been mentioned in the answers but you can't pay seven pounds eight and eightpence out of six pounds because £7/8/8 > £6.

Comment: @Transistor that is Aunt Jane's question, not mine, to which Jack has replied in the play.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Prior to February 1971, Britain had a currency system where 12 pennies ('pence') (abbreviation 'd') made one shilling, and 20 shillings made one pound. The sum of seven pounds, eight shillings and eight pence would be written in a variety of ways, e.g. £7.8s.8d, £7/8/8, £7-8-8. It would be spoken informally as "seven pounds eight [shillings] and eight [pence]". I once bought a tape recorder (from Headquarter and General Supplies in Croydon, if anyone is interested) that was advertised to cost '£4-19-6'. Especially in signs or posters, the separator between pounds, shillings and pence could be any of a number of characters, or just spaces. Here we see colons. The returnable crate (for a baby carriage) was charged at five shillings - 5/-, the dash representing 'no pence'. Sums of shillings and pence were often written with a stroke separator, and smaller sums between £1 and £5 might be written thus, e.g. 59/6 was £2.19.6.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, in the current system £7.88 is spoken as **seven pounds and eighty-eight pence, right?**

Comment: @mahmudkoya: that's right. Many people say "pee" rather than "pence" (I say "pence"). Most often people say "seven pounds eighty-eight", without "and" or "pence/pee".

Comment: Prior to decimalisation, nobody said 'pee' for 'pence', but people did say 'dee' for the 'd' symbol for old pence. I once got into an argument on here about that, and produced a 1915 quote from HG Wells to prove it.

Comment: @mahmudkoya To follow on from Colin Fine's comment, the "and" is almost *never* used - the "pence/pee" is optional.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica thanks. +1

Comment: "seven pounds and eighty-eight pence, right?" if someone feels the need to be precise yes, in normal speech they are just as likely to say "seven eighty-eight" and let the units be implied by the context.

Comment: In some British novels in the 1970's they say "new pence".

Comment: People used 'new pence' for a relatively short period after Decimalisation Day. I was  aged 18 and I noticed that older people carried on long after my contemporaries had fully adopted the 'pee/pence' terminology.

Comment: Typo/nitpick: I think 59/6 would be £2.19.6. You'd need 79/6 to make £3.19.6.

Comment: Yes, I fixed it 29 mins ago, roughly when you commented.

Comment: I feel no-one has completely answered the question until they point out that seven pounds, eight and eightpence (£7/8/8) is £7.43 (and a third) in the new money.

Comment: The coins introduced at decimalisation carried the words *new penny* or *new pence* on the reverse side (see e.g. http://laborenglishzone.blogspot.com/2018/02/decimalisation-day-2018.html). They've all since been replaced by smaller versions which just say *penny* or *pence*.

Comment: I honestly don't know why this answer has got so many votes. People should stop. This way lies madness!

Answer (score 8):

The usual way of saying an amount in pounds, shillings and pence was with "and" between the shillings and pence amounts.

So "seven and six" meant "7 shillings and 6 pence". "Eight pounds eight and eight" would be your amount of 8 pounds 8 shillings and 8 pence.

If there were no pence, the word "shillings" was often used, i.e. "eight pounds ten shillings" not just "eight pounds ten".

It's worth mentioning that there has been considerable currency inflation since the 1970s. When pounds shillings and pence were still in use, many common items cost much less than one pound. For example when I reached the legal age to buy alcohol, the price of a pint of beer was less than 2 shillings in some local pubs - i.e. *less than 10p* in current decimal money, compared with a few pounds today. So prices less than a pound like "two and six" were commonly used in shops, etc.

The modern convention is usually just to say the numbers of pounds and pence, e.g. "seven eighty-eight" means "7 pounds 88 pence". If the number of pence is small, people often add "and" after the pounds and "pee" after the pence, e.g. "seven pounds and three pee" not just "seven three".

Note, an amount like "seven eighty-eight" is slightly ambiguous, because it could also mean "788 pounds", but it is usually obvious whether you are talking about a large or a small amount of money.

As David42 said in a comment, in the early 1970s when the UK currency changed to decimal, and both types of coins were in use together, people often said "old pence" or "new pence" to avoid confusion.

Comment: Shillings is not used any longer nowadays?

Comment: @dan: No.  (Well, unless you count people who are deliberately trying to sound old-fashioned, or discussing inflation from pre-1971 prices.)  The shilling as a *notational* unit was abolished with decimalisation.  Shilling *coins* remained in circulation (as 5p) until 1990 when they were replaced with a smaller 5p coin.

Comment: @dan04 also two shilling coins worth 10p.

Comment: Actually, you would sometimes hear "eight pounds ten" to mean £8.10.0.  I post-date decimalisation, but have heard it like that recently on re-runs of _Hancock's Half Hour_ from the mid 1950s.

Comment: To further confuse things, there were also _florins_ (two shillings), _half-crowns_ (two shillings and sixpence - 8 of them made a £1) and _ha'pennies_ (half-penny). The weird currency system (_Galleons_, _Sickles_, _Knuts_ etc.) that J.K. Rowling describes in the first _Harry Potter_ is probably a parody of this.

Comment: @OscarBravo - I can see how the florin/half-crown might confuse people who are not used to the pre-decimalisation currency however in reality the use of them is no more confusing than the American coinage system (Nickel/Dime/Quarter) as opposed to the 'new' British system of just naming coins by value (5p/10p/25p etc)

Comment: @OscarBravo, if you want to confuse things, don't forget the farthing, the three-farthing, and the three-halfpence coins.

Comment: @Separatrix Not to mention the thrupenny bit and the sixpence...

Comment: Separatrix - No three-halfpence or three-farthing coins were produced after 1582.

Comment: An Irishman in a pub once threatened to 'fill my mouth with threepenny bits', but I was not so short of money that I needed that.

Comment: @EdHunter US coins are officially referred to by their cent values (1-cent, 5-cent, ...) and the common term "dime" and "quarter" are their relative value (1/10, 1/4).

Comment: @gormadoc, but "nickel" just indicates the metal it was historically made of.

Comment: Sometimes the old money is, only half-jokingly, known as the Lsd system (more often £sd). Pounds were written L for libra (or a fancy L -- £ -- if you had a posh typewriter), shillings s for solidus (not s for shilling!), pennies d for denarius). It's a system which the UK inherited for the Roman Empire and was once in wide use around Europe. What makes the UK weird is that we were so late changing it. In the same way, rarely within Europe, none of the UK's day-of-the-week names ever got Christianised. Not much changes here!

Comment: @gormadoc: Actually, what's written on our coins is "one cent", "five cents", "one dime", and "quarter dollar".  Yes, a "dime" is a *unit* of money, not just the name of a coin.  Apparently, the original intent was to have a three-tier dollars/dimes/cents system, analogous to pounds/shillings/pence, but decimalized; and it would be just as valid to notate half a dollar as "5d" as it still is to write "$0.50" or "50¢".

Comment: @ThePhoton "Nickel" is not the official term but the common term. It was originally the "half-dime," which was the relative value ((1/10)/2) and is now the "5-cent coin."

Comment: @gormadoc, I was replying to where you said "the common term...are their relative value".

Comment: @ThePhoton I didn't originally mention that "nickel" was a relative value, though...

Comment: @gormadoc No, but I felt you implied this was a general rule, for which you gave two examples. I was pointing out that the most common coin you didn't mention as an example breaks the rule. (And in fact other less common coins like the half dollar and dollar are commonly named by their values)

Comment: @dan04 That's just the design. The official terms (and names) are their cent values: https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/faqs/Coins/Pages/denominations.aspx